# Solving $\int\sec^3(x) \, dx$ example, trouble getting from step to step

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I'm doing an example problem that is solving the integral of $\sec^3(x) \, dx$. The first step shown in the problem takes it from that to: $$\sec(x)\tan(x) - \int \sec(x)\tan^2(x) \, dx$$ The book doesn't say how they get to that and I can't figure it out. Not sure if it's some combo of the other stuff in the chapter I'm not noticing or if it's some identity or rule they're making use of I've forgot since my trig is a little rusty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\int \Big(\sec x\Big) \Big(\sec^2 x\,dx\Big) = \overbrace{\int u\,dv = uv - \int v\,du}^\text{integration by parts} = \sec x\tan x - \int \Big(\tan x\Big) \Big( \sec x\tan x\,dx \Big)
$$